# Cannot Install SSL Certificate. Certificate keeps disappearing in IIS

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2016, godaddy, iis-10

I am trying to install godaddy's SSL certificate on Windows Server 2016. I did everything on the MMC console and everything looks right. I followed all the steps from this website https://ca.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-iis-10-server-27349
When I completed 'Complete Certification Request', the ssl is added to IIS but when i refresh iis, the cerficate disapears.
I tried solution from this link https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9773/2238/ssl-disappears-from-the-certificate-list-on-windows-server/.
When i perform **certutil -repairstore my Serial_number**, it asks to connect smart card. I tried disabling "Smart card plug and play service", I am still getting "Connect Smart Card" plug. Does anyone have solution regarding this issue?

I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you run CMD as administrator? Thisd sounds a bit like 3rd party stuff is trying to authenticate against the computer's store.

Comment: yes, i ran the command as administrator.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-whole-story-of-server-certificate-disappears-in-iis-7-7-5-8-8-5-10-0-after-installing-it-why-b66e802baa38 Check it out.